# Failed to connect to Github repo from Jenkins

Tags: github, jenkins

I have a **Jenkins** installation on a **ubuntu** server. And, **Github** installed on another server. I am trying to connect the repository from **Jenkins** using Git plugin.
I am using HTTPS to connect the **Github** URL. And, when I input the URL in the Repository URL field, I get the following error.

```
Failed to connect to repository : Command "/usr/bin/git ls-remote -h https://server.com/51363775/test1.git HEAD" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: fatal: unable to access '_https://server.com/51363775/test1.git/': server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wqq27.jpg)

Comment: Seems like you are using a self-signed ssl cert for your git server. Jenkins does not trust it out of the box. You could add your self-signed cert to the trusted key store of the jvm on your jenkins host. See [here](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/203821254-How-to-install-a-new-SSL-certificate)

Comment: What OS are you running on. if it is debian based, install `ca-certificates` and `ca-certificates-java`, and the run `update-ca-certificates -f`. This will add all known certificates to the java cert store (`/etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts`) and create a new `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt`.